# Php api calls another php api - body lost

Tags: php, api, curl

I've created a php api which needs to call another api I've created too. I've tested the second one using Postman and it gives the expected result. But when I test the first one, the second api does't receive the body data. It seems that it is lost.

Is there something wrong with my code below?

Many thanks for your help.

//The first api which needs to be called  (http://mylocalsite.com/user/create)

```php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// display data
var_dump($data);

// Displayed result
"NULL\n"
```

//The second api which have to call the first one

```php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$url = "http://mylocalsite.com/user/create";
$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $userData);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$response = curl_exec($client);
curl_close($client);
```

Data sent

```
{
    "username" : "anonymous_api",
    "password" : "secret123!",
    "firstname" : "anonymous_api",
    "lastname" : "anonymous_api",
    "email" : "anonymous_api@bookingpro.com",
    "role" : "USER"
}
```

Expected data

```
{
    "username" : "anonymous_api",
    "password" : "secret123!",
    "firstname" : "anonymous_api",
    "lastname" : "anonymous_api",
    "email" : "anonymous_api@bookingpro.com",
    "role" : "USER"
}
```

Actual data

```
"NULL\n"
```

Comment: just for info: when you call 2 different PHP files of one project on the same server through HTTP calls - you do it wrong

Comment: So, how can I do it right?

Comment: MVC pattern, class autoload, reusable code, etc

Comment: Actualy I have different projects but on the same server

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be in `$response`

test it by using

```
echo $response;
```

Your `$data` is not useful in your 2nd script.

Comment: Your should also check for `curl_error` or `false` in `$response` for failures

Comment: I've an error in my code for the seconde api in the post. I've ```$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); ``` But after I've tried to send it the first api with $userData variable ```curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $userData); ```

Comment: Please update your question to what you have tried.